# How can I access Windows 10s volume OSD information?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, mediacontroller

I'm talking about this one:

[image]

Specifically, I'd like to access the media information (artist, title etc.) that are currently played.

Looking at the docs, the [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols) and [MusicDisplayProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.musicdisplayproperties) seem to be the way to go, but it seems that I can only access these if my current application initiated the playback.

However, I just want to get the current information set by whatever application put them there. Is that possible, or is access of these limited to the application that created them?

Comment: use FindWindowEx to look for a window class **NativeHWNDHost**. if you got the handle to the window and next next try EnumWindows/EnumChildWindows to get all items

Comment: UWP apps run in a security sandbox that strictly limits what they can do.  Poking around in another process is not possible.  Share contracts are [described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/index).